Importance sampling weights when sampling without replacement
Suppose we have a function $f(x_i)$ for a discrete variable $x_i$ (indexed 1 to N). We would like to calculate $\sum_{i=1}^N(f(x_i))$. Instead of the full sum, we sample some subset of size M from $x_i$, using an importance sampling distribution $P(x_i)$ without resampling (renormalizing the importance distribution after each step).
In the typical importance distribution method, we would weight each sample by $1/P(x_i)$ before summing the results of the sampling. I'm trying to understand if we "need" these weights for sampling without replacement. It seems like there's some tradeoff here - the estimator is biased without the weights, but in the extreme case where M=N, it would make no sense to use the reweighting scheme.

You can answer this by considering the other extreme case $M=1$ and computing the expectations of (a) the sample mean and (b) the inverse-probability weighted sample mean.

Note that an importance sampling estimator only uses the marginal distribution of each $x_i$ since this is a linear combination of the $f(x_i)$'s whose validity is solely expressed in terms of its expectation.
